# Apache-camel Seda endpoint, BlockWhenFull not acknowledged

Tags: apache-camel

```
from("seda:myqueue?size=2&blockWhenFull=true").process(sleep());



private Processor sleep() {
                return new Processor() {                    
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                        System.out.println(curTime() + " Going for sleep sleepid=" + body );
                        Thread.sleep(5000l);                        
                        System.out.println(curTime() + " Done sleep sleepid=" + body );
                    }
                };



for (Integer i = 0; i <5; i++) {            
            Exchange exchange = new DefaultExchange(context);
            exchange.setPattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly);
            exchange.getIn().setHeader("header", i);
            exchange.getIn().setBody(i.toString());
           System.out.println("sending msg to seda");
           Exchange send = template.send("seda:myqueue",exchange);
           System.out.println("done:"+i);

        }
```

"`BlockWhenFull`" not acknowledged  i.e if size is set to 2 and i send 3 msg in a loop with body as "1" , "2" and "3" than i get sleep msg for only "1" and "2" and i guess third msg is silently dropped even when i have set the "`BlockWhenFull`" as true.

***What am i doing wrong?***

version: 2.15.3

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the `blockWhenFull` on the producer, eg where you send

```
template.send("seda:myqueue?blockWhenFull=true",exchange);
```

Comment: ohh i see| than why did not get a exception as mentioned in doc "By default, an exception will be thrown stating that the queue is full."http://camel.apache.org/seda.html